# :after element not getting positioned over div

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently working on a small landing page for my personal game project.
I wanted to have a nice link:hover effect, so I am using an :after element to position a trianle above the link, but the positioning is not working.

I threw together the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niktehpui/xUjCC/1/).

Currently the triangle is positioned absolute and this is working in loads of tutorials, but it is not working with my span-elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to set `position: relative` to the `<span>` element:

```
span.linktopbar {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

Also, I'd set `display: inline-block` to prevent the scroll bar to appear when hovering.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is always in the middle is because the linktopbar.xi always takes its absolute position from the containing div which holds all the anchor elements (div.footer). You have given the .xi element left:50% which means it will get the first containing element with position:relative and work out based on that elements x,y & width.

You need to give each anchor element an xi OR you need to use some .js to work out the .position() (in jQuery) of the element and then adjust the .xi left attribute value